# How to remove certain variables from some of df in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of df with name filelist. If I want to remove variable `date` from some of df, how can I do it at once?

I have a datafile summary like this, basically it tells us `filelist[["A"]] <-filelist[["A"]] %>% select(-date)`, etc.. I am not that good at list and don't know how I can do it on list without going through them one by one:

[image]

```
datasummary <-structure(list(FileName = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"
), Keep = c(NA, NA, "Y", "Y", NA, "Y", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Take a look at `lapply`. It is a good choice for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'datasummary' NA are the ones where we need to remove 'date' from those 'FileName' elemenets of 'filelist', `filter` the rows where 'Keep' is NA and `pull` the 'FileName', loop over the subset of 'filelist' and remove the date column with `select`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
nm1 <- datasummary %>%
          filter(is.na(Keep)) %>% 
          pull(FileName)
filelist[nm1] <- map(filelist[nm1], ~ .x %>% 
          select(-date))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
nm1 <- subset(datasummary, is.na(Keep)$FileName
filelist[nm1] <- lapply(filelist[nm1], subset, select = -date)
```